# UIScrollView bad contentSize height when in Landscape (ipad)

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview, landscape, vertical-scrolling

I've a problem using a UIScrollView with subviews and vertical scrolling.

When in portrait mode it scrolls fine, but when in landscape, even if I set an arbitrary value (let's say 1400px), it doesn't really scroll along that size, removing around 400 pixels and it stops before the content is fully visible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Posting some code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to set

```
yourScrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

It should resize the scrollview height.